# Float text to the right of figure and figcaption

Tags: css, html, image, figure, caption

I discovered the "figure" and "figcaption" elements today. How do I wrap text next (right) to the image and caption.

```
<div>
<img alt="Hannibal Regional Medical Building" src="https://hannibalregionalmedicalgroup.org/Portals/0/locations/hannibal_regional_medical_building_375.jpg" width="375" height="178" style="text-align: left;" />
<figcaption>Hannibal Regional Medical Building</figcaption>
</div>
<div>
 <p>
 <span>Hannibal Regional Medical Group 
 <br />
 6500 Hos​pital Drive<br />
 Hannibal, MO  63401
 </span>
 </p>
</div>
<div>
<p><span>To make an appointment,<br />
please call 573-629-3500
</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear,  can you provide a link or example of what you want ?

Comment: You may have discovered those elements, but apparently you didn't check their usage and validity rules: "*[a] [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) element; the `<figcaption>` element must be its first or last child.*" ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The HTML `<figcaption>` element represents a caption or a legend
>   associated with a figure or an illustration described by the rest of
>   the data of the `<figure>` element which is its immediate ancestor.
>
> **Permitted parents:** A `<figure>` element; the `<figcaption>` element
>   must be its first or last child. -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption)

That means using a `<div>` tag as the immediate ancestor for a `<figcaption>` is invalid HTML in your example. To fix that you need to replace the `<div>` with `<figure>`.

```
<figure>
  <img src="" alt="">   
  <figcaption>...</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And to make the rest of text to display on the right hand, there are many options, such as using `float` is the most common way.

```
figure {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the first `div` with `figure` (only this is valid) and then put `float:left;` on the `figure`:

```html
<figure style="float:left;">
  <img alt="Hannibal Regional Medical Building" src="https://hannibalregionalmedicalgroup.org/Portals/0/locations/hannibal_regional_medical_building_375.jpg" width="375" height="178"/>
  <figcaption>Hannibal Regional Medical Building</figcaption>
</figure>
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Hannibal Regional Medical Group<br/>
    6500 Hos​pital Drive<br/>
    Hannibal, MO  63401</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <span>To make an appointment,<br/>
    please call 573-XXX-XXXX</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<figure style="float:left;">
<img alt="Hannibal Regional Medical Building" src="https://hannibalregionalmedicalgroup.org/Portals/0/locations/hannibal_regional_medical_building_375.jpg" width="375" height="178" />
<figcaption>Hannibal Regional Medical Building</figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/6va2nqad/3/